# How to login in AzureAD with Ionic & react?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, logging, azure-active-directory

I created an app with Ionic + React and I want to use login with AzureAD. I followed this example:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-react-samples/typescript-sample/src/index.tsx

BUT apparently it only works with the browser, because when I make the APK with Android and open the app on a tablet, I have an error right at the beginning, in the main.tsx, this error show in the console

window.crypto.random UUID

[message error from devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7YI7.png)

I guess it's not the best way to sign in with AzureAD in ionic, but I didn't find another way. Any suggestions?

This is my main.tsx:

````
msalInstance.initialize().then(() => {

  const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
  
  if (accounts.length > 0) {
    msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
  }

  try {
    msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: EventMessage) => {

      if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && event.payload) {
          const payload = event.payload as AuthenticationResult;
          const account = payload.account;
          msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error al inicializar MSAL:", error);
  }

  const container = document.getElementById('root');
  const root = createRoot(container!);

  root.render(
      <App pca={msalInstance}/>
  );
});```
````